# Firefox and Chrome return value of date toISOstring() is different

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, iso

There appears to be a difference in the ISO String representation of a date object in Chrome and Firefox. If one runs the below sample code in Chrome and Firefox, different results are obtained:

```
new Date(  "1-Nov-2010 00:00 UTC").toISOString();
```

Firefox: `-002010-11-01T00:00:00.000Z`

Chrome: `2010-11-01T00:00:00.000Z`

What is `-00` and why does Firefox behave differently to Chrome?

Comment: For a start, you're using a non-standard date input. So, different handling is to be expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a non-standard date format. Firefox is parsing it and sees "oh, you want the year `-2010`", Chrome seems to parse it a bit better, but I'd just suggest not using that particular string format for the dates.

Comment: "*I'd just suggest not using that particular string format for the dates.*" - I'd suggest not using *any* string format for dates other than the standard one.